# Local storage retrieval issues - sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2, local-storage

I can successfully save data to local storage and retrieve it. However, if I refresh my browser and then try to recall the data in local storage, it fails to do so.
I am saving the data like so;

```
var eventStore = Ext.getStore('Details');

if(null == eventStore.findRecord('id', currentEvent.data.id)) {
    eventStore.add(currentEvent);
}

eventStore.sync();

eventStore.sort([{ property: 'dateCreated', direction: 'Desc' }]);

console.log('Data saved, store has ' + eventStore.getCount() + ' items');
console.log(localStorage);
```

When i refresh my browser and check my console, the entry is there, but when i try to call it like below, it fails.

```
var store = Ext.getStore('Details');
var storeId = store.findRecord('id', 'LC');
console.log('Details store has ' + store.getCount() + ' items');
console.log(storeId.data.id);
return;
```

i am new to Sencha touch and would greatly appreciate any advice as to what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
Simply updated sencha touch to the latest version and all works as should.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check property **phantom: true** of the new created model. If it is not set or is false the proxy will not synchronize it is remote store, but keeps only in store's 'memory' :)

I'd advise save your event record via **model.save()** rather than store's sync() call. Have a look at http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-save. Proxy can be defined for Model as far as for Store.

Cheers, Oleg